# Column named parent in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Does postgresql allow columns named "parent"?

Neither

```
SELECT id, parent, name FROM address WHERE id=1
```

nor

```
SELECT id, "parent", name FROM address WHERE id=1
```

give me an actual result. Instead I get:

```
ERROR:  column "parent" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT id, "parent", name FROM address WHERE id=1
                   ^
In statement:
SELECT id, "parent", name FROM address WHERE id=1
```

The table very certainly has a column called parent.

Comment: @ypercube It's postgres, so no.

Comment: Oh yes, thnx, and I just checked, parent is not reserved in Postgres.

Comment: Can you post the table's CREATE statement?

Comment: The problem maybe with the `name` field though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually quite insidious. There was nothing wrong with anything. The whole issue was the APC cache holding onto something it shouldn't have. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The word "parent" does not appear to be a [keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in postgresql so something else is the issue.

When you surround the column name with double-quotes, the column name becomes case sensitive. Can you post the output of "\d address"? This would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.